# AS3 how to load in external images in a loop?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image, load

I'm making a highscore table in flash using AS3, I have successfully got working code that displays the names and the scores but also part of my high score table it needs to display the users country flag. The images for the flags are stored on a remote server.

Now I know how to load in a single image and add it to my movie clip but things get very complicated when I want to load in 20+ by iterating through a loop. I've looked at many examples and just cant adopt the sample code to work for me. Anyway without a further a do here is what I have so far.

`// Load High scores from server
var hiscoreloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
hiscoreloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, highScoresLoaded);
var hiscorexml:XML;
function highScoresLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    hiscorexml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var hsList:XMLList = hiscorexml.highscores.highscore;
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < hsList.length(); i++)
    {
        this["hs_score_"+i].text = zeroPad(hsList.score.text()[i], 8);
        this["hs_name_"+i].text = hsList.name.text()[i];
        // Load in Flag
        // url of flag will be: "http://wfwxg.philosophydesign.com/images/flags/" + hsList.country.text()[i] + ".png"
        // Move clip instance name the above image needs adding too will be: this["hs_flag_"+i]
    }
}
hiscoreloader.load(new URLRequest("http://wfwxg.philosophydesign.com/includes/top20.php?nocache=" + new Date().getTime()));`

Can anyone amend my code to do what I'm after?

Many Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution.

Practically , I would advise to encapsulate concerns so that your code is not too tightly coupled. Right now, you handle almost everything in one single function while assigning the result data to your main MovieClip. This is why I created an Array to hold the XML data as well as the loaded images.

One possible structure could be to:
- first retrieve the XML data and assign it to the data Array.
 
- loop thru the data Array to load the images , and assign the loaded content to the relevant Object.
- After all the images have loaded , use the data Array to set your display

```
       // Load High scores from server
        var hiscoreloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

            //Create an Array to hold your XML data
        var data:Array = [];

        hiscoreloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, highScoresLoaded);

        var hiscorexml:XML;

        function highScoresLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
          hiscorexml = new XML(e.target.data);
              var hsList:XMLList = hiscorexml.highscores.highscore;

          for(var i:uint = 0; i < hsList.length(); i++)
          {
             //here we create a new Object to hold the retrieved data
             //and add it to the data Array
            data[i] = { 
                             hs_score:zeroPad(hsList.score.text()[i], 8), 
             hs_name: hsList.name.text()[i], 
             flagURL:"http://wfwxg.philosophydesign.com/images/flags/"
                             + hsList.country.text()[i] + ".png",
             mc_name:"hs_flag_"+i.toString();
            };

             //load the images
             var loader:Loader = new Loader();
             configureListeners(loader.contentLoaderInfo);  
             loader.name = i.toString();
             loader.load( new URLRequest( data[i].flagURL ) );
          }
        }

        function configureListeners(info:LoaderInfo):void
        {
            //add all your event listeners here
            info.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , completeHandler );
        }

        function removeListeners(info:LoaderInfo):void
        {
            //remove all your event listeners here
            info.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , completeHandler );
        }


    function completeHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var index:int = int( event.currentTarget.loader.name );
        //add the image data to your data Array
        data[index].flag = event.currentTarget.loader.content;
        removeListeners( event.currentTarget );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I've re-labeled the code you have given and fixed one error in the completeHandler where you have index but then use i. This is the code I have now: http://pastebin.com/zk3AWKN9 When I run I get this error: 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:LoaderInfo.

Comment: I can't test your code, trying to load the XML throws a security error. It's hard to debug just by looking at it :) Try to use breakpoints , if not try to split your code in parts. For instance , test the loop first by commenting out the loader code , if that works , comment out loader.load only... and so on , until you find where it breaks. This code is fairly straightforward , I can't see the reason for this error, I'm thinking it may be due to your environment , maybe a variable name clash ...

Comment: In my previous comment I highlighted the code where it was breaking at. The error to me meant that it didnt like event.currentTarget being passed to a :LoaderInfo type. So I've changed this to be just an Object instead. The code works but I really don't know if this is correct and it is correctly cleaning up the event listeners. Here is the code I now have: http://pastebin.com/1dLzxtDc

Comment: Your code should be fine. I'm actually surprised at this error as I don't remember getting anything similar. In any case, I've changed a couple of lines in order to type event.currentTarget as a LoaderInfo instance. You could always test your code with the hasEventListener() method , just to make sure it all works fine...